# Routing: how do I redirect to a url when a parameter is missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have routes like this:

```
example.com/{category}/articles.
```

There isn't a route for

```
example.com/{category}
example.com/
```

I want to redirect all that traffic to

```
example.com/{category}/articles with a default value.
```

I've read that I can use default values with a `RouteValueDictionary`:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ArticlesAll", "{category}/articles/", "~/ArticlesPage.aspx", false, new RouteValueDictionary { { "category", "cats" } });
```

But that doesn't do any redirecting.

Would I need another route to forward to the one above or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup these two routes:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("ArticlesAll", "{category}/articles/{*value}", "~/ArticlesPage.aspx");
routes.MapPageRoute("CatchAll", "{*value}", "~/ArticlesPage.aspx");
```

to catch anything and redirect to your desired page. I just assumed where you want to lead your users, change the aspx part as needed. Keep in mind that you can use  {value} to access the whatever the user wrote.

For example if they wanted to navigate to `dogs` and you wanted to redirect to `dogs/articles/ArticlesPage.aspx`, you should use:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("CatchAll", "{*value}", "~/{value}/articles/ArticlesPage.aspx");
```

**EDIT**

If you want to actually redirect to the new URL and not just serve up the right page, you can use the `CatchAll` route to redirect to a page (say `Redirect.aspx`) that's sole purpose is to parse data from the `RouteData` object, construct the new URL and `Redirect`.

Comment: Would this keep the url the same though? If the user enters the site and types in `example.com`/, I would want them to be redirected to `example.com/cats/articles`, similarly if they typed `example.com/cats` I would want them redirected to `example.com/cats/articles`.

Comment: You are right, it does not redirect. Let me look into it further.

Comment: All I could think of is routing to a page that's sole purpose is to parse the data from `RouteData` and `Redirect` to the proper url from codebehind.

Comment: This helped me find _a_ solution. Essentially I'm using the catchall route with default values, forwarding it to `Default.aspx` and then doing a `Response.RedirectToRoute()` in the codebehind.

Comment: @gin93r Cool, I've updated my answer if you want to accept it, or you can just write your own answer with the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is a bit unclear, but let me offer what I usually do.

If you are trying to make it so that two similar links can be written, for example `www.example.com/read/penguin/article/` and `www.example.com/read/panda/article`. I would just write the whole string / URL with a variable in the middle:

```
private string destination = "penguin";
private string url = "www.example.com/read/" + destination + "/article/";

void Test () {
    destination = "lion";
    text.URL = url;
}
```

Sorry, I may have made gramatical mistakes in my code, but I hope you get the point. I may have *completely* misunderstood you though, so clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Yeah I think you misunderstood. I apologize if I wasn't clear. Essentially: If the user enters the site and types in `example.com`/, I would want them to be redirected to `example.com/cats/articles`, similarly if they typed `example.com/cats` I would want them redirected to `example.com/cats/articles`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I don't have much knowledge on webforms, but if I had to guess I would set up a function to test for if it has "example.com" in the input. If "example.com" and "example.com/cats" result in the same output, just test for "example.com". Again, I don't usually work in this area of c#, but I hope you can find an answer!